# How to load a specific session using express-session in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, express-session

I need to create a websocket where I can connect to it from a different domain (websocket runs on 10.0.4.18:8020 and the client will establish connection from 10.0.4.160:443.)

Each user must have a unique session to be able to reuse his/her user data after authentication takes place.

Since the client "aka user's browser" is on a different host, I am having hard time keeping the session tied with with the client that creates it on page reloaded event!

I thought of this workaround to solve this problem

1. Create session using `XMLHttpRequest()` function from the client, then return a sessionID to the client
2. Save the sessionId in the user's browser using `localStorage`
3. Pass the sessionId to socket.io every time a user connects to the websocket.
4. Websocket then takes the sessionId and reloads it to make it available all over again.

To eliminate session fixation attack, I am going to add few more validation step to make sure the sessionId is not hijacked by using the client's IP and agent data.

Additionally, I need to fire a `setInterval()` method which will make external API call every second and updates the session variable.

**Question**

How can I properly reload a session data where I can auto save the variables without having to directly use store.get() to load the session data and save them?

**Here is what I have done**

I created the session using a file system. On every request I have to load the session store using `store.get()` method, update the session data, and then save it. But the problem that I have is every time I want to update the session as you can see my below code.

Here is what I have done!

```
var app = require('express')(),
    https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    fileStore = require('session-file-store')(session),
    base64url = require('base64url'),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    cookieParser = require("cookie-parser"),
    env = require('./modules/config');

var server = https.createServer(
    {
        key: fs.readFileSync('certs/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('certs/cert.pem')
    }, app).listen(env.socket.port, env.socket.host, function () {
    console.log('\033[2J');
    console.log('Websocket is running at https://%s:%s', server.address().address, server.address().port);
});

var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var icwsReq = require('./modules/icws/request.js'),
    icwsConn = require('./modules/icws/connection.js'),
    icwsInter = require('./modules/icws/interactions.js'),
    sessionValidator = require('./modules/validator.js');

var icwsRequest = new icwsReq();
var sessionChecker = new sessionValidator();

var sessionStoreFile = new fileStore({path: './tmp/sessions'});

var sessionOptions = {
        store: sessionStoreFile,
        secret: env.session.secret,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: false,
        cookie: {
            path: '/',
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
            secure: true
        }
    };

app.use(session(sessionOptions)); // session support for the app

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));  //allows to pupulate req.body in the REST/PUT post requests!


// Set access control headers on every express route.
app.use(function (req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('x-powered-by', 'Express');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    next();
});


//Middleware for authorizing a user before establishing a connection
io.use(function(req, next) {

    var sessionID = req.handshake.query.token || '';
    var token = req.handshake.query.auth || '';

    var origin = req.handshake.headers.origin;
    var ip = req.request.socket.remoteAddress; 
    var userAgent =  req.handshake.headers['user-agent'];

    if(!sessionID || !token){
        console.log('No Session found with this token! ' + sessionID);
        return next(new Error('No Session found with this token!'));
    }

    sessionStoreFile.get(sessionID, function(err, session){

        // session updated
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return next(new Error(err));
        }

        if(!session){
            console.log('Session Could not be loaded');
            return next(new Error('Session Could not be loaded'));
        }

        if(    session.token != token
            || session.ip != ip
            || session.agent != userAgent
            || session.origin != origin
        ){

            session.token = null;
            session.ip = null;
            session.agent = null;
            session.origin = null;

            sessionStoreFile.set(sessionID, session);

            console.log('This session is invalid! Please sign in');
            return next(new Error('This session is invalid! Please sign in'));
        }

        next();

    });
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    var sessionID = socket.handshake.query.token;

    //load the session with the ID sessionID
    sessionStoreFile.get(sessionID, function(err, session){

        //add the socket.id to the queue
        session.clients.push(socket.id);

        //Save the session data after adding the connection to the queue
        sessionStoreFile.set(sessionID, session, function(){

            //Get the current session data "including current socket.id"
            sessionStoreFile.get(sessionID, function(err, session){

                //get an instance of icws connector
                icwsRequest.setConnection(session.icwsHost, session.icwsPort);

                var interactions = new icwsInter(icwsRequest);

                //Call the API everysecond, update the session then save the session
                setInterval(function(){
                    sessionStoreFile.get(sessionID, function(err, session){
                        //call the API and return the new data
                        session.queue = interactions.updateQueue();
                        //save the new data every second
                        sessionStoreFile.set(sessionID, session);
                    }

                }, 1000);

                //handle ICWS interactions
                socket.on('interaction', function(data){

                    var  task = data.task || '',
                         phone = data.phone || '',
                         interactionId = data.interactionId || '',
                         queueName = data.queueName || '';

                    //Place a phone call
                    if(task == 'call'){
                        interactions.call(phone);
                    }

                    //External transfer
                    if(task == 'eBlindTransfer'){
                        interactions.blindTransferCallExternal(interactionId, phone);
                    }           

                    //Internal Transfer
                    if(task == 'iBlindTransfer'){
                        interactions.blindTransferCallInternal(interactionId, queueName);
                    }                   

                });

                //send a chat message to all browser's tabs associated with the currect session
                socket.on('chat', function(msg){

                    var clients = session.clients;

                    console.log(clients);

                    for (var i in clients) {

                        var socketId = clients[i];
                        console.log('Client Said: ' + msg + ' socket Id: ' + socketId);
                        io.to(socketId).emit('chat', {message: 'Server Said: ' + msg});
                    }

                });

                //handle disconnect
                socket.on('disconnect', function(msg){

                    var index = session.clients.indexOf(socket.id);

                    if(index > -1){
                        session.clients.splice(index, 1);

                        //save session after removing a client
                        sessionStoreFile.set(sessionID, session, function(error){

                            if(!error){
                                console.log('Closing tabs: ' + socket.id);
                                console.log(session);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                //handle errors
                socket.on('error', function(msg){
                    console.log('Error Message: ' + msg);
                }); 

            });

        });

    });

});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('welcome: ' + req.sessionID);
});


app.get('/handshake/:token', function (req, res) {

    var origin = req.headers.origin;
    var ip =  req.connection.remoteAddress;
    var userAgent =  req.headers['user-agent'];

    if(!req.params || !req.params.token || !ip || !origin || !userAgent){
        console.log('Missing Request!');
        return false;
    }

    if(!originIsAllowed(origin)){
        console.log('This is a cross-domain attack!');
        return false;
    }

    req.session.token = req.params.token;
    req.session.ip = ip;
    req.session.origin = origin; 
    req.session.agent = userAgent;
    req.session.clients = [];

    req.session.save(function(err){

        if (err) {
            connectionError(res, session);
        } else {
            res.json({
                token: req.sessionID
            });
        }

    });
});



function originIsAllowed(origin) {
    // put logic here to detect whether the specified origin is allowed.
        var allowed = env.session.allowedOrigins || []

        if(allowed.indexOf(origin) >= 0){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
};
```